# No Google Play Store on Xiaomi 11 Lite 5G

Tags: google-play-store, xiaomi

I got a Xiaomi 11 Lite 5G, and it had Google Play Store and I used it to install Pokemon Go and used its Dual app mode.

And then I had two Pokemon Go running, but then I tried installing Plants vs Zombies, and Angry Birds 2, but it stopped somewhere during the game start up.

And then now, Pokemon Go cannot log in, and I tried Google Play Store and it could not go in.

I then followed the instructions on the [Mi Community](https://c.mi.com/thread-2310338-1-0.html#:%7E:text=If%20your%20Play%20Store%20app,in%20the%20Google%20Play%20Store.&text=Go%20back%20into%20your%20Settings%20and%20tap%20on%20Account%20again.) but the methods do not work, and since I got the phone on eBay, I thought it may be good to do a factory reset just in case the phone has something installed by the third party that I am not aware of.

After the factory reset, there is no Google Play Store, and when I go to Settings -> Account, there is no way to add any Google account either.

I can go to apkmirror.com to install Google Play Store, but it'd run and then flash and then quit.  I also installed Pokemon Go from apkmirror.com, but then there is no Google account to use either and it doesn't allow to go on. (which is what I used to log in, using my previous phones).

So what can be done that can get back the Google Play Store?

Comment: I would try to download a full firmware image for your device and install it https://www.getdroidtips.com/xiaomi-mi-11-lite-5g-europe-stable-rom/

Comment: I also saw YouTube and another blog post mentioning https://google-installer.en.uptodown.com/android do you know if that is alright?

Comment: I am not familiar with Xiaomi devices, but I would assume that all Xiaomi device come with pre-installed Google services (even for those devices only sold in China?). Therefore if you do a factory reset and afterwards Google Services and Play Store are missing means that the device is manipulated. Effectively the person who manipulated could have installed back door or remote admin software as system app. Therefore my advice is to fully erase the device and install a known to be genuine firmware (with Google apps). Otherwise you can not be sure the device is really under your control.

Comment: according to https://soyacincau.com/2021/02/07/xiaomi-gms-google-apps-services-support-official-response it says International model comes with Google (GMS), and "some" domestic version has it. Mine is shipped from ShenZhen, China (bought from eBay)... so mine falls under "domestic"... I'd imagine if it is a Xiaomi selling in Hong Kong, it probably will have GMS. (by the way, I'd imagine if people install "back door", they can fake it 100%, meaning they also install GMS as well as the back door... which is why I feel uneasy to buy smartphone on eBay (but sometimes it is the only option)

Comment: When you go to any app page on the Google Play website, you will get an option to bring it up in Google Play. Try clicking on that option, and observe the results. This will at least tell you if it's actually hidden on your system somewhere. I've seen apps disappear from the UI completely while still being on the hard drive. It's worth checking. If it is still there by chance, opening it should bring it back into the land of the living.

Comment: Is Google Play one of the apps that checks for root permission now? Most apps of which Google has any sort of hand in development (e.g. Pokemon go) will not install on rooted devices. If it really is gone, I'd bet money on the fact that this has something to do with it. What version of Android is your device running? As you likely already know, Android 10 and 11 made a lot of changes in the name of *"security"* which devastated the root user community. It wouldn't surprise me if this is one of them.